# How to Update old values with new values in Spark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

How to Update old values with new values in Spark

E.g., in fruits Column I want to replace Apple value with Banana using PySpark

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df.replace({'Apple': 'Banana'}, 'fruits')
```

Comment: A little heads up to anyone wandering here, this will only replace the value in df, not in the original files from where you have read the df. Since it is not clear in question, this is a suitable answer.